# Seaborn Scatter Plot with Color gradation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-science

I'm looking to relate 2 variables, `co2` and `avg_tmp` over time using a Seaborn Plot. I want a scatterplot with `year` on the X-axis, `co2` on Y-axis and `avg_tmp` represented through a graded color scale (darker meaning higher temperature).

I am able to do this with matplotlib like this:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='year', y='co2', c='avg_tmp', s=100)
```

[image]

What's the seaborn equivalent for this plot. Example data here:
https://gist.github.com/raghothams/790eaa3fe7fea034bc687b786eda8995

Comment: seaborn and pandas plotting are both built on top of matplotlib.  You should be able to mix and match between the three as needed.

Comment: Are you looking for some specific feature that you don't have with the pandas plot in your example?

Comment: Nope, I'm looking to do exactly what I've done in the plot above, but using Seaborn's nicer looking plots.

Answer (score 3):

you can give graded color to avg_tmp. So for that use [seaborn scatter plot](https://indianaiproduction.com/seaborn-scatter-plot) function sns.scatterplot() with palette parameter.

Here, I am showing scatter plot with tips Data Frame but you can replace by your data-set variable

```
hue = "avg_tmp"
size = "avg_tmp" # for increase the size of points
```

-

```
# import libaries
import seaborn as sns # for data visualization

# load tips dataset from GitHub seaborn repository
tips_df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

#create seaborn scatter plot
sns.scatterplot(x = "tip", y = "total_bill", data = tips_df, hue = "sex", 
                size ="sex", sizes = (100, 300), palette = "gist_gray")
```

Output >>>

[image]

**Palette** values : `Accent, Accent_r, Blues, Blues_r, BrBG, BrBG_r, BuGn, BuGn_r, BuPu, BuPu_r, CMRmap, CMRmap_r, Dark2, Dark2_r, GnBu, GnBu_r, Greens, Greens_r, Greys, Greys_r, OrRd, OrRd_r, Oranges, Oranges_r, PRGn, PRGn_r, Paired, Paired_r, Pastel1, Pastel1_r, Pastel2, Pastel2_r, PiYG, PiYG_r, PuBu, PuBuGn, PuBuGn_r, PuBu_r, PuOr, PuOr_r, PuRd, PuRd_r, Purples, Purples_r, RdBu, RdBu_r, RdGy, RdGy_r, RdPu, RdPu_r, RdYlBu, RdYlBu_r, RdYlGn, RdYlGn_r, Reds, Reds_r, Set1, Set1_r, Set2, Set2_r, Set3, Set3_r, Spectral, Spectral_r, Wistia, Wistia_r, YlGn, YlGnBu, YlGnBu_r, YlGn_r, YlOrBr, YlOrBr_r, YlOrRd, YlOrRd_r, afmhot, afmhot_r, autumn, autumn_r, binary, binary_r, bone, bone_r, brg, brg_r, bwr, bwr_r, cividis, cividis_r, cool, cool_r, coolwarm, coolwarm_r, copper, copper_r, cubehelix, cubehelix_r, flag, flag_r, gist_earth, gist_earth_r, gist_gray, gist_gray_r, gist_heat, gist_heat_r, gist_ncar, gist_ncar_r, gist_rainbow, gist_rainbow_r, gist_stern, gist_stern_r, gist_yarg, gist_yarg_r, gnuplot, gnuplot2, gnuplot2_r, gnuplot_r, gray, gray_r, hot, hot_r, hsv, hsv_r, icefire, icefire_r, inferno, inferno_r, jet, jet_r, magma, magma_r, mako, mako_r, nipy_spectral, nipy_spectral_r, ocean, ocean_r, pink, pink_r, plasma, plasma_r, prism, prism_r, rainbow, rainbow_r, rocket, rocket_r, seismic, seismic_r, spring, spring_r, summer, summer_r, tab10, tab10_r, tab20, tab20_r, tab20b, tab20b_r, tab20c, tab20c_r, terrain, terrain_r, twilight, twilight_r, twilight_shifted, twilight_shifted_r, viridis, viridis_r, vlag, vlag_r, winter, winter_r`